# How to search in all registers

Tags: register

Is there a nondestructive way to search a pattern in all registers, like redirecting `:reg` to some register and then paste it to a new buffer and perform the search there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the list of registers that match a pattern with:

```
:let regs=split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789/-".', '\zs')

:echo filter(regs, 'getreg(v:val) =~ "the_pattern"')
```

Or if you really prefer to paste all registers into a buffer in order to search interactively (and not programmatically) -- I leave the creation of scratch buffer out

```
:let regs=split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789/-".', '\zs')
:call map(regs, '"\"".v:val. "  ".getreg(v:val)')
:put=regs

" or, if neither the noise nor the joined lines bother you
put=execute('registers')
```

Comment: ```:echo filter(regs, 'getreg(v:val) =~ "the_pattern"')``` desn't work (gives [])

Comment: @user10982983 What is you pattern? Have you seen there are two strings embedded? Also, this is a program oriented solution, from this you have a list and can do whatever you wish with it. To display it, `join(thelist, "\n")` is often required for instance.

Comment: Now it is ok, the problem was that ```filter``` destroys the ```regs``` variable and therefore the list with the register names must be generated every time before calling the ```filter```. Thanks!

Comment: Oh. Yes indeed. The other possibility in those cases is to `copy(res)` in `filter()` call.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new unnamed buffer and then  put the output of `:reg` into it with

```
:enew
:put =execute('reg')
```

**Note that the output of `:reg` is truncated to terminal width.**

Where `=` is the "expression register" and `execute('reg')` is the expression. See `:help @=`.

The function `execute()` executes a command and returns the output as string. See `:help execute()`.

---

Or, to show the power of Vim:

```
command -nargs=1 RegSearch echo join(filter(split(execute('reg'), "\n"), {i, v -> v =~ <q-args>}), "\n")
```

Inner-to-outer:

- `execute('reg')` is already known
- `split(..., "\n")` split into a list of lines
- `filter(..., {i, v -> v =~ <q-args>})` only keep those line that match the commands argument (see `:help <q-args>` and  `:help lambda`)
- `join(..., "\n")` join the kept list elements into a string separated by newlines.

Then use it like this:

```
:RegSearch <searchterm>
```

Searchterm is a regular expression. If it contains whitespaces, they have to be escaped with a backslash.

<sub>I love it when it is doable on one line :-). And then Christian writes a comment ... :-/ He is right.</sub>

Comment: Note, that `:reg` truncates the register content. So it might not match. In theory, one should be able to do something like this as well: `:filter /patter/ :reg`, however, the `:reg` command is not supported by the `:filter` command. Sounds like a plausible whishlist bug to me

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a gist from romainl](https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7)

Here is my tweaked version of the gist.

```
" Redirect the output of a Vim or external command into a scratch buffer
command! -nargs=1 Redir
            \ tabnew |
            \ setlocal nobuflisted buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile |
            \ call setline(1, split(execute(<q-args>), "\n"))
```

Now, you can do `:Redir reg` to open a new tabpage with output of `:reg`. Then do what you gotta do.

Comment: Now we can use `execute()` that has less side effects than `:redir`. But we can also simply use `filter()` on `getreg()` results. See my answer.

Comment: @LucHermitte, I edited my function. Could you take a look and see if it's okay? Also, why would execute() be better than redir? Except of course easier to use.

Comment: It relates to silencing the execution. Also `setline()` can take a list, or there is simply `:put=`

Comment: @LucHermitte, I edited again. Is this alright? Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: If it gives the right result, then this is alright :) We can always add more. For instance, my scratch buffers are also usually `readonly`, they have a name that starts with `pluginfeaturename://`, and I can dismiss them with `q`. Others will be perfectly happy with `new` or `vnew` and so on.